# Any way to reformat "json" file so I can extract the data?

Tags: json, node.js, file

A colleague of mine sent this file over to me asking me to extract the data into a database.... issue is, it is not formatted correctly. (It is supposed to be a json file... even sent as orders.json).

Here is the file contents (The other files are much larger, this is just a snippet):

```
[
   "Buyer: Jane Doe  ",
   [
      "jane Doe",
      "Street Here",
      "State, ZIP",
      "Phone : 8888888"
   ],
   "Ship By: Wed, Oct 11, 2017 to Thu, Oct 12, 2017",
   "Deliver By: Mon, Oct 16, 2017 to Thu, Oct 19, 2017",
   "Shipping Service: Standard",
   [
      [
         "Product name",
         "SKU: 99999999999",
         "ASIN: 999999999",
         "Condition: New",
         "Listing ID: 99999999999",
         "Order Item ID: 9999999999",
         "Customizations:",
         "Size: 16 Inches",
         "Monogram Letters: BSA",
         "Color: Unpainted (goes out in 48 hrs)"
      ]
   ],
   "A",
   "Wed, Oct 4, 2017, 8:03 PM PT",
   "114-7275553-4341048",
   [
      "1"
   ]
]
```

I believe I will have to go through this slowly and use unnecessary methods to get this to look nice and work... unless I am missing something?

As of right now I can't really access the data in a efficient way.

Comment: i mean... that's valid json. It's not in a very useful form, but, it IS json, and can be easily parsed and then iterated over with javascript.

Comment: I think the issue I am having is just the way the data is collected... to get the sku I have to use var sku = data[0][5][0][1].split(" ").splice(1);   Sort of insane....

Comment: Write your own parser. Use a regular expression sparingly, striving for char counting or positioning if you can.

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking I am going to have to just go through it and match characters in order to extract the right information.

Comment: yeah, it's not gonna be pretty

Comment: Well thanks for the help guys. It's just gonna be ugly multi-dimensional array work until I can convince him to scrape the data in a more efficient way.

Comment: Are the last three items important? They seem to be the only ones without a label embedded.

Comment: I believe the 'A' is just for Amazon. The date is important as I believe that is the actual order date.